# Sine function using Taylor expansion (C Programming)

Tags: c, function, trigonometry

[Here](http://www5.picturepush.com/photo/a/7232713/1024/Anonymous/2.jpg)  is the question..

This is what I've done so far,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long int factorial(int m)
{
    if (m==0 || m==1) return (1);
    else      return (m*factorial(m-1));
}
double power(double x,int n)
{
    double val=1;
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        val*=x;
    }
    return val;
}

double sine(double x)
{
    int n;
    double val=0;
    for (n=0;n<8;n++)
    {
        double p = power(-1,n);
        double px = power(x,2*n+1);
        long fac = factorial(2*n+1);
        val += p * px / fac;
    }
    return val;
}

int main()
{
    double x;
    printf("Enter angles in degrees: ");
    scanf("%lf",&x);
    printf("\nValue of sine of %.2f is %.2lf\n",x,sine(x * M_PI / 180));
    printf("\nValue of sine of %.2f from library function is %.2lf\n",x,sin(x * M_PI / 180));
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the program works perfectly fine from 0 to 180 degrees, but beyond that it gives error.. Also when I increase the value of `n` in `for (n=0;n<8;n++)` beyond 8, i get significant error.. There is nothing wrong with the algorithm, I've tested it in my calculator, and the program seems to be fine as well.. I think the problem is due to the range of the data type.. what should i correct to get rid of this error? 
Thanks..

Comment: I don't know for sure if this is it, but you were talking about datatype range... Have you tried having `factorial` return a `long long int`?

Comment: @rene the value differs from the standard value.. for example at 270 degrees i get -0.44, but the standard value is -1.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure yes, tried that.. didn't help..

Comment: (I assume you mean "from 0 to pi" rather than "from 0 to 180 degrees" because the Taylor expansion works in radians, not degrees.) You need to reduce the magnitude of the `px` and `fac` variables. For example, refactor the expression from x^(2n+1)/(2n+1)! to product(i=1 step 2 to 2n+1){x/i}. Note also that convergence is slow when you get far away from 0.

Comment: He does the conversion to radians.

Answer (score 2):

`15!` is indeed beyond range that a 32bit integer can hold. I'd use doubles throughout if I were you.

The taylor series for `sin(x)` converges more slowly for large values of x. For x outside -π,π. I'd add/subtract multiples of 2*π to get as small an x as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the error is due to the range of the data type.  In sine(), you are calculating the factorial of 15, which is a huge number and does not fit in 32 bits (which is presumably what long int is implemented as on your system).  To fix this, you could either:

1. Redefine factorial to return a double.
2. Rework your code to combine power and factorial into one loop, which alternately multiplies by x, and divides by i.  This will be messier-looking but will avoid the possibility of overflowing a double (granted, I don't think that's a problem for your use case).

Comment: Did what, option #1 or #2?  I've tried out option #1 and it works fine, on both 32-bit and 64-bit machines.  Did you remember to change both the `long int` return type of `factorial` to `double`, as well as the `long` storage type of `fac` to `double`?

Answer (score 1):

You need range reduction. Note that a Taylor series is best near zero and that in the negative range it is the (negative) mirror image of it's positive range. So, in short: reduce the range (by the modula of 2 PI) to wrap it it the range where you have the highest accuracy. The range beyond 1/2 PI is getting less accurate, so you also want to use the formula: sin(1/2 PI + x) = sin(1/2 PI - x). For negative vales use the formula: sin(-x) = -sin(x). Now you only need to evaluate the interval 0 - 1/2 PI while spanning the whole range. Of course for VERY large values accuracy of the modula of 2 PI will suffer.

Answer (score 0):

You may be having a problem with 15!.

I would print out the values for p, px, fac, and the value for the term for each iteration, and check them out.

Answer (score 0):

You're only including 8 terms in an infinite series.  If you think about it for a second in terms of a polynomial, you should see that you don't have a good enough fit for the entire curve.

The fact is that you only need to write the function for 0 <= x <=\pi;  all other values will follow using these relationships:

```
  sin(-x) = -sin(x)
```

and

```
sin(x+\pi;) = -sin(x)
```

and

```
sin(x+2n\pi) = sin(x)
```

I'd recommend that you normalize your input angle using these to make your function work for all angles as written.

There's a lot of inefficiency built into your code (e.g. you keep recalculating factorials that would easily fit in a table lookup; you use power() to oscillate between -1 and +1).  But first make it work correctly, then make it faster.

Comment: His code works fine with only 8 terms on my 64-bit system; I'm pretty sure the problem is simply overflow of the long int.  (Of course what you mention will improve accuracy for large angles, but I don't think that's the source of his problem.)

Comment: Why the downvote? All of this is still correct and relevant and will apply even when the data type range issue is fixed.

Comment: Thank you, Platinum.  I agree - my points don't address the root cause that is the factorial, but the rest of it is quite correct.

Comment: @Platinum, I didn't downvote it; I agree the comment is correct, just that this is likely not the root cause.

Comment: yes that is not the cause.. the algorithm works fine even for the range `0 to 8` on my calculator.. and for higher angles, even without using the trigonometric manipulations..